# Is it good practice to apply batch normalization on frozen weights?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, batch-normalization

Im wondering if it's common to use batch norm layer on those layers that have frozen weights and biases. In my particular case, i have pretrained VGG19 and weights trained on ImageNet. What im trying to do now is training this network with pretrained weights with batch norm layer added before every single nonlinearity. My question here is that is it good practice to use batch norm layer on every layer even though earlier layer's weights are frozen meaning not trainable? My first though was it is good practice because even though those earlier layers are not trainable, still batch norm parameters are trainable so the input to those frozen layers should be normalized and will have good distribution. If you have any idea about this please give me intuitive explanation. Sorry for my poor English and thank you for your attention.

Comment: Its not about being good practice or not, using batchnorm in a network that was not trained with it will probably simply not work at all. The whole network should be trained with batchnorm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).